# Set default value on configurable drop down in magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento, configurable-product

I have a Configurable Product with 3 Options - here is what the drop down menu looks like on the product page.

```
Bundle Deals            

* Required Fields
Choose an Option...
- Single Product £10
- 5 Product Bundle £50
- 10 Product Bundle £100
```

Default value on page load is `£10.00` but if I hit add to cart it flags up with - `* Required Fields` & user is prompted to select an option from the drop down.

By default I would like the drop down menu to load with - `Single Product £10` as the default value.

Hope that all makes sense?  I can't find this functionality in the Magento version 1.9 CE, which I am using

**FINAL EDIT >>** thanks to everyone for helping - got a fix - Very glad! visit link.. **similar to a suggestion here but something in the code seemed to work for me**

`http://iamvikram.com/magento-remove-choose-an-option-from-configurable-products-dropdown/`

A thank you msg has been mailed :)

Comment: Might have some luck on http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: glad that you have it sorted out. I also like to remove the Choose an Option from the drop down cause it's useless if the option is required.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes` in your magento admin and search for your attribute.

Click to edit and select `No` to `Values required.`

Hope it will work.

JQuery to default select first value is -

```
jQuery('#attribute135>option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: we need to select the first option as default selected and not to   by pass validation

Comment: Alright, so you are having 3 attributes and you want to select first option as default selected for all 3 attributes ?

Comment: Thanks SlimShadddyyy - I tried that - I still get flagged for Required fields.

Comment: What if you just remove the `Please Select` message from Custom Option Dropdown on Magento Product View and making the first option as default selected ?

Comment: Yeah - If it can select the first attribute as default I would be very happy :)  

Or if I can turn off the validation (Required Fields) that would also be great - But I think configureable products are always Required..

Comment: Yeah, you need to select atleast one option for configurable product. You could do it using jquery to select first option of dropdown.

Comment: - The Choose an Option... msg is hard coded in Magento.. If i can edit the JS file to take out the msg that would also be great..!  Not sure which file it is tho.. possibly a .phtml file.. 

Using JQuery is an option..

Comment: You can use that jquery in product view page using script tag. I have added jquery code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @TBI - Couldnt get the jQuery to work..  Added to the file **frontend/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**   ..have template path hints set on so I got the path...   Put the line inside a <script> tag as --  `jQuery('#attribute138>option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true);`
**138** is my number acording to Chrome...  Am I trying this correct - or have I missed something.. Very grateful for any help.

Comment: Try using the jQuery val() , this will also trigger the change event                                              jQuery('.catalog-product-view .super-attribute-select').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).find("option:nth-child(2)").val());
});

Answer (score 0):

Copy below file in your local

```
/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml


<select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
<option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
</select>
```

It shows '`Choose an Option...`' as a default value

You can change it like below to simply select the first real element in your select:

```
$$('#attribute525 option')[1].selected = true;
```

Check with your **attributeid**. The above is just an example.

Comment: Thanks @Slimshadddyyy  - Cant get this to work.. If I change the text from "Choose an Option..."  to "Choose a Product..."  Still the old msg Choose an Option comes up in the drop box.. I have refreshed cache & indexes.. Maybe a different file is actioning the function.. ?  

I added the 
'$$('#attribute525 option')[1].selected = true;'

- still lookin at this

Comment: @dan_code89 on your product page, inspect the dropdown and check the attributeid of `select`. For me its `attribute502`. For you it could be something else. Pass that `attributeid`

Answer (score 0):

This could get tricky if you have 2+ options (it's confusing but what you describe above is 1 option with 3 selection), says Color and Size. Assuming Color is the first Option, Size's selection will be updated once Color is selected.

For example, you have a shirt available in Red in size (S,L) and Blue in size (M,L), once you select Blue, Magento observe the event 'onChange' of the Color option and update the Size option to M, L.

This is what I would do to get it done correctly in PrototypeJS:

```
<script type='text/javascript>
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);

        document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
            var el = $('attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>');
            el.selectedIndex = 1;
            el[0].remove();
            if ("createEvent" in document) {
                var ev = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                ev.initEvent("change", false, true);
                el.dispatchEvent(ev);
            } else {
                el.fireEvent("onchange");
            }  
</script>
```

in `configurable.phtml`, please note the fireEvent / dispatchEvent.
el[0].remove will get rid of "Select an option.."

This is the least intrusive method that I know of

Comment: Have tried this @William Tran  - sorry I couldnt get it working.. error msgs...  **Can you explain it a bit more & the fireEvent?.** I am not a JavaScript writer.. Just HTML & CSS are my main thing.. Would be Much Obliged for a solution here :/

Comment: My answer is for configurable product with one option:
you have to populate $_attribute before getting to the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
Open app\design\frontend\[your package]\[your theme]\template\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable.phtml
```

Now add the below java-script code after :-

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);


function fireEvent(element,event){

if (document.createEventObject){

// dispatch for IE

var evt = document.createEventObject();

return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)

}

else{

// dispatch for firefox + others

var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");

evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable

return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);

}

}

Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {

spConfig.settings[0].selectedIndex = 1;

obj = spConfig.settings[0]; // this grabs the first select item

Event.observe(obj,'change',function(){});

fireEvent(obj,'change'); // this simulates selecting the first option, which triggers

spConfig.settings[1].selectedIndex = 1; // this selects the first option of the second attribute drop menu
});
```